# Can I have an OUT parameter of type CURSOR in HSQLDB?

Tags: java, oracle, unit-testing, stored-procedures, hsqldb

I have a java web project that talks to an Oracle db through stored procedures. When the stored procedures need to return a RecordSet, I have the stored proc accept an OUT parameter of type SYS_REFCURSOR. Then the Java code iterates over the record set to read the values. I'm trying to Unit test the DOA layer, and I started to use HSQLDB to mock out the database, but it doesn't seem possible to have a stored proc in HSQLDB take an OUT CURSOR parameter. I haven't ever used HSQLDB before, so please forgive my ignorance about how it can be used.
Has anyone dealt with this before?
I feel like my options are:

1. Use MS SQL that actually allows me to have the Stored Procedure do a select, rather than having to use an OUT SYS_REFCURSOR to pass data back to the Java code. This is more wishing thinking on my part, my company won't let me use MS SQL :(.
2. Find a way in PL/SQL to have a stored procedure return records without an OUT parameter in a way that can be consumed by the Java caller.
3. Find an alternative to HSQLDB that lets me mock out stored procedures during unit-testing which behave more like Oracle.
4. Don't bother unit-testing the DOA layer. This seems like where I'll end up, it's not critical as there is almost no business logic in the DOA layer that has value in testing, it's more of just trying to improve my code coverage statistics.

For reference, here is a typical call to a stored proc:

```
   private static final RowMapper<MyRecord> RECORD_ROW_MAPPER=
        (rs, i) -> new MyRecord(rs.getInteger("OWNER_ID"),
                                rs.getString("NAME"), 
                                rs.getString("DESCRIPTION"));

   private static final SimpleJdbcCall getRecordProcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(dataSource)
                              .withSchemaName("app_data")
                              .withProcedureName("getMyRecords")
                              .returningResultSet("OUT_RECORD", RECORD_ROW_MAPPER);

   public ArrayList<MyRecord> getMyRecords(int ownerId) {
      SqlParameterSource in = new MapSqlParameterSource()
                              .addValue("IN_OWNER_ID", ownerId);
      return getRecordProcCall.executeFunction(ArrayList.class, in);
   }
```

And my corresponding PL/SQL function:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getMyRecords (
  IN_OWNER_ID IN  NUMBER,
  OUT_RECORD  OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
)AS
BEGIN
  OPEN OUT_RECORD FOR 
  SELECT OWNER_ID, NAME, DESCRIPTION
  FROM MY_RECORD
  WHERE OWNER_ID = IN_OWNER_ID;
END
```

I understand that I could do this trivial example case with direct SQL and not use a stored procedure, but it's only trivial to show how I'm accessing the DB in this post. In reality, I'm doing a significant amount of work that's best done within a stored procedure.

Comment: If you are using Oracle 12c you can take advantage of [DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_sql.htm#ARPLS68279) to mimic they way MS SQL returns [implicit record sets](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/implicit-statement-results-12cr1) from stored procedures.

Comment: That sounds like it will work, I have to read up on it for sure. Thanks!

Comment: Sentinel, This worked. If you resubmit this as an answer, I'll accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Oracle 12c Release 1 (12.1) the [`DBMS_SQL`](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_sql.htm#ARPLS058) package includes the [`RETURN_RESULT`](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_sql.htm#ARPLS73893) procedure which returns the result of an executed statement to the client application similar to the way MS SQL Server procedures implicitly return record sets.

Tim Hall of the ORACLE-BASE blog has a good posting on [Implicit Statement Results in Oracle Database 12c](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/implicit-statement-results-12cr1)

Answer (score 2):

You can get a cursor out of an HSQLDB stored procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getMyRecords (
 IN_OWNER_ID IN  NUMBER
) 
 BEGIN ATOMIC
  DECLARE MYCURSOR CURSOR FOR RETURN FOR
   SELECT OWNER_ID, NAME, DESCRIPTION
   FROM MY_RECORD
   WHERE OWNER_ID = IN_OWNER_ID;
  OPEN MYCURSOR;
 END
```

On the JDBC side, it should work by getting a ResultSet after the call with getResultSet() and getMoreResults().

BTW, you can mock the procedure signature by creating a dummy type such as

```
CREATE TYPE SYS_REFCURSOR AS INT;
```

and using the same signature as the original procedure.