# How to define Out CURSOR in HSQLDB and access it via Java/Junit

Tags: java, junit, hsqldb, resultset

I have a java web project that talks to an Oracle db through stored procedures. Stored proc accepts two input and 1 OUT parameter of type SYS_REFCURSOR. Then the Java code iterates over the record set to read the values. I'm trying to Unit test the DOA layer, and I started to use HSQLDB to mock out the database, but it doesn't seem possible to have a stored proc in HSQLDB take an OUT CURSOR parameter.

I referred the following post [Can I have an OUT parameter of type CURSOR in HSQLDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40291411/can-i-have-an-out-parameter-of-type-cursor-in-hsqldb) and created a mock procedure signature by creating dummy type. But when accessing the result i'm facing issue. I am getting null resultset. How to access the cursor output in Java. (Note: Everything is working fine when access the real DB)

**PL/SQL function:**

```
PROCEDURE sp_get_first_time_code_partid (
    i_partid          IN     NUMBER,
    p_delivery_code   IN     VARCHAR2,
    ret_recordset        OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
....
....
END sp_get_first_time_code_partid;
```

**Java program**

```
  public void populateFirstTimeCodeInfo(CallableStatement callableStatement) throws SQLException
  {
    ResultSet resultSet = (ResultSet) callableStatement.getObject(3);
    while (resultSet.next())
    {
      System.out.println(resultSet.getString("SSN_NUM"));
    }
  }
```

**Junit Test Case**

```
statement.execute(
        "create table PKG_ARO_FIRST_TIME_CODE.ARO_FIRST_TIME_CODE (ssn_num VARCHAR2, create_date VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, first_time_code VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, "
                + "code_sent_source VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,code_expire_date VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL)");

statement.executeUpdate(
        "insert into PKG_ARO_FIRST_TIME_CODE.ARO_FIRST_TIME_CODE (ssn_num, create_date, first_time_code,code_sent_source,code_expire_date) values ('894463762', '2/13/2019 11:03:02 AM',"
                + "'WMKNSMWY','C','2/19/2019')");
```

**Dummy Type**

```
statement.execute("CREATE TYPE SYS_REFCURSOR AS VARCHAR2;");
```

**Mocked Stored procedure with dummy type**

```
statement.execute(
"CREATE PROCEDURE SSADMIN.PKG_ARO_FIRST_TIME_CODE.SP_GET_FIRST_TIME_CODE_PARTID(IN i_part_id VARCHAR2, IN p_delivery_code VARCHAR2, OUT ret_recordset SYS_REFCURSOR)\r\n"
 + READS SQL DATA DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1\r\n + BEGIN ATOMIC\r\n +
 "DECLARE ret_recordset CURSOR WITH RETURN FOR SELECT * FROM PKG_ARO_FIRST_TIME_CODE.ARO_FIRST_TIME_CODE;\r\n"
 + "open ret_recordset;\r\n" + "END");
```

when executing

```
ResultSet resultSet = (ResultSet) callableStatement.getObject(3);
```

resultSet is null

If I replace "READS SQL DATA DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1" with "READS SQL DATA" I am getting
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hsqldb.result.Result cannot be cast to java.sql.ResultSet

Answer (score 0):

Your OUT parameter will not contain the CURSOR that your procedure opens (this parameter is only needed for mocking the call to the Oracle DB). You need to prepare the call to the procedure, execute it, then use getResultSet():

```
 Connection conn = ...;
 CallableStatement call = conn.prepareCall("call sp_get_first_time_cod_partid(?, ?)");
 call.setString(1, "val1");
 call.setString(2, "val2");
 call.execute();
 ResultSet result = call.getResultSet();
```

It is documented in the Guide: http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/sqlroutines-chapt.html#src_returning_data